# With out Touching project code I want disable the all sop,s

Tags: java

i am  working on old project,so in that project so many sop's are there in so many files like all most 5000 files.we don't have permissions to touch the code so i want disable all those sop's. plz provide a solutions to me

Comment: Suggestion: beg the powers that be to change your permissions and then touch the code. Then change the SOP's to logging statements whose settings *can* be changed without touching the code.

Comment: ok , but sop's are there in more than 5000 files so it is time taking process we don't have that much time,

Comment: StackOverflow is a community of developers who donate their time to help people resolve problems with tasks that they may be having troubles with. You'll get a better response if you rephrase your question so your not asking for someone to provide a full solution but asking to solve a problem with effort you've put into solving your own problem. If you want a straight solution you'll have better luck paying someone to solve the task for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a UNIX system, you can pipe the output to `/dev/null`. Consider a Java file called Test. Usually, you would call this using

```
java Test
```

And thus getting the output send to the screen. Instead of having it sent to the screen, you may just pipe (send) it `/dev/null` (nothing):

```
java Test > /dev/null
```